# How can I download the Blender open movies in the highest quality available?

Tags: installation, documentation

I have a rural internet connection, which means limited bandwidth and sometimes problems with streaming. Sometimes, for example, we can't stream something to our living room TV because we get frequent pauses or low enough resolution it makes it hard to watch.

I would like to download the Blender open movies in a high resolution (at least 1K where available) so I can watch them and not have to worry about playback issues due to poor internet and so I can rewatch them without it taking more bandwidth.

It doesn't look like there is a page to actually download these movies. Is there a place I can download them or is the only option to capture them on YouTube?

(And to pre-empt other questions: Yes, I know about Starlink. We're due later this year. Yes, I know the movies aren't that long, still, for a lot of reasons I'd like to be able to rewatch them and study them and it's easier, with internet that can often be slower than DSL, to just download them during a low use period like after 2AM.)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the open movies produced by [Blender Studio](https://studio.blender.org/), you can find them at the [films](https://studio.blender.org/films/) page, but might have to be a subscriber to be able to download directly from the Studio's web site.

If you mean other open movies produced by different studios, and there are many, especially short films, I believe that there is no central repository and you'll have to search to see if the studio has a copy available for downloading by searching for the movie's title.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I've checked that link, but when I pick a link to one of the films on that page, on the page that comes up, it includes the option to watch, but not to download. If you're a member, could you verify that downloading is an option for members?

Comment: I am.  I did.  It might not be for every movie, but it definitely is for most of them.

Comment: @tango, ask me about a specific movie and I can see if the full version is available.

Comment: Thanks for checking! I also looked into the subscription. It looks like it would be a big help to me in learning Blender for some of what I want to do with it. Right now I'm involved in finishing work on our lot that'll take me another month or two. After that, I'll have a lot more time for Blender work. When I get there, then I'll sign up for a subscription.